# Android Java Interface Callback onPostExecute nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, callback

I have the following classes:

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.webapp;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                showSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {

            try {
                final String result = msg.toString();
                JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                mainView(jObject);
              }
              catch(JSONException e) {
                e.getCause();
              }


        };
    };

    public void mainView(JSONObject result){

    }

    public void showSettings(){
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Oncreate","1");
        String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/webapp/server.php?method=getPageIndexLiveValues";
        Log.d("Oncreate","2");
        JSONhandler parser = new JSONhandler(this);
        parser.execute(url);

        Log.d("Oncreate","3");



    }


        public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject result) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
           Log.d("onRequestComplete","complete");
            try {
                TextView test1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                test1.setText(result.getString("GP").toString()+"W");
                TextView test2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                test2.setText(result.getString("IP").toString()+"W");
                TextView test3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                test3.setText(result.getString("EFF").toString()+"%");

                Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                today.setToNow();


                TextView textViewDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDateTime);

                textViewDay.setText(today.monthDay+"-"+(today.month+1)+"-"+today.year+" "+today.format("%k:%M:%S"));             // Day of the month (0-31)

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



}
```

JSONhandler.java
    package com.example.webapp;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONhandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    //private static final JSONObject JSONObject = null;
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONhandler(Main main){

    }

    public interface MyCallbackInterface {
        public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject json);
    }

    private MyCallbackInterface mCallback;

    public void JSONParser(MyCallbackInterface callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) { 
        Log.d("getJSONFromUrl","1");        
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;


    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("doInBackground","1");
        String url = params[0];
        Log.d("doInBackground",url);
        Log.d("doInBackground","2");
        return getJSONFromUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("onPostExecute",result.toString());

        //In here, call back to Activity or other listener that things are done
        try{
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject("sumIn");
            Log.d("onPostE Sum",json.toString());
            mCallback.onRequestCompleted(json); //<<<<<< See bel
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.d("onPostE Sum",json.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
!!!!ERROR MESSAGE!!!!
E/AndroidRuntime(2237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2237): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at com.example.webapp.JSONhandler.onPostExecute(JSONhandler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(2237):     at com.example.webapp.JSONhandler.onPostExecute(JSONhandler.java:1)
and a lot more.....
```

I'm very new to Java/Android and can't figure out whats happening here.
Hope some one can help me.

UPDATED CODE:
I updated the code, but still get the error on Line 107 (//<<<< see below).
When json is initialized correct, the code runs in the mCallback error.
When json is null, the TryCatch catches the error and logs "empty".

The new code for Main and change the code on suggestion of Sam.

```
package com.example.webapp;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.webapp.JSONhandler.MyCallbackInterface;

    public class Main extends Activity implements MyCallbackInterface  {


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                showSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {

            try {
                final String result = msg.toString();
                JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                mainView(jObject);
              }
              catch(JSONException e) {
                e.getCause();
              }


        };
    };

    public void mainView(JSONObject result){

    }

    public void showSettings(){
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Oncreate","1");
        String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx";
        Log.d("Oncreate","2");
        JSONhandler parser = new JSONhandler(this);
        parser.execute(url);

        Log.d("Oncreate","3");



    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject result) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("onRequestComplete","complete");
            try {
                TextView test1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                test1.setText(result.getString("GP").toString()+"W");
                TextView test2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                test2.setText(result.getString("IP").toString()+"W");
                TextView test3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                test3.setText(result.getString("EFF").toString()+"%");

                Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                today.setToNow();


                TextView textViewDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDateTime);

                textViewDay.setText(today.monthDay+"-"+(today.month+1)+"-"+today.year+" "+today.format("%k:%M:%S"));             // Day of the month (0-31)

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



}
```

The new code for JSONhandler and change the code on suggestion of Sam.

```
package com.example.webapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONhandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    //private static final JSONObject JSONObject = null;
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONhandler(Main main){

    }

    public interface MyCallbackInterface {
        public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject json);
    }

    private MyCallbackInterface mCallback;

    public JSONhandler(MyCallbackInterface callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) { 
        Log.d("getJSONFromUrl","1");        
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;


    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("doInBackground","1");
        String url = params[0];
        Log.d("doInBackground",url);
        Log.d("doInBackground","2");
        return getJSONFromUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("onPostExecute",result.toString());

        //In here, call back to Activity or other listener that things are done
        try{
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject("sumInvrters");
            Log.d("onPostE Sum",json.toString());
            mCallback.onRequestCompleted(json); //<<<< see below 
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.d("onPostE Sum","empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one question: are you new to programming? If that's the case, I suggest you to search about what's a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), understand that it raises because a variable/object/something is used when it has `null` value and debug to check why is `null`. Only after trying to solve this and haven't got a solution, come here and ask people to give you a hint.

Comment: What line causes the exception?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I'm new to Java, but i tried to understand whats happening (see a my log.d, i did this to hopefully see whats going wrong). I understood that line //<<<< see bel(ow) went wrong, but since JSONObject json logged with the excepted values, i lost it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the LogCat and your note:

```
mCallback.onRequestCompleted(json); //<<<<<< See bel
```

It appears `mCallback` is null, since you forgot to define it. Let's change things around a little:

1. Have your Activity implement your callback:

   ```
   public class Main extends Activity implements MyCallbackInterface {
   ```

   And add `@Override` to `onRequestCompleted()` if necessary.
2. Remove the `JSONhandler` constructor that expects an Activity and replace it with one that expects your interface.

   ---

   So remove this code:

   ```
   public JSONhandler(Main main){

   }

   public void JSONParser(MyCallbackInterface callback) {
       mCallback = callback;
   }
   ```

   ---

   Use this constructor instead:

   ```
   public JSONhandler(MyCallbackInterface callback) {
       mCallback = callback;
   }
   ```

Now this code should work just fine:

```
JSONhandler parser = new JSONhandler(this);
parser.execute(url);
```

Comment: thanx for you're response! the line you mentioned is indeed the line that causes the exception. I changed the code, but i still get the NullPointerException. When JSONObject json is null, the code runs without a problem, but (i think) this is because the Try catches the null from json. But when JSONObject json is filled, the code runs into the NullPointerException at line: mCallback.onRequestCompleted(json);

Will post the updated code soon, hope you can help me further.

Comment: You still have the constructor that expects `Main`, remove this from your code: `public JSONhandler(Main main){}`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the values on line 107 was null.  Probably mCallback, assuming the line you have commented "See below" is 107.  This is because JSONParse was never called.  Notice that this is a function not a constructor-  was it meant to be a constructor?

Comment: It was meant as a constructor and Sam also mentioned it in his code examples. thanx for you're input.